# Porque mis pdfs no soportan imagenes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, dompdf

Estoy generando pdfs para tickets usando DOMPDF y Laravel-7 y todo funciona a la perfección. Pero cuando quiero agregarle a mi PDF una imagen el mismo ya no carga y me devuelve un error de que el tiempo de espera fue superado.

```
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

Esta es mi vista:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>Ticket PDF</title>
  </head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <table>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <img src="{{ url('backend/dist/img/axis.jpg') }}">
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <h1>GLOBAL TEC TRADE SRL</h1>
                          <br>
                          <p>+54 9-11-2300-300</p>
                          <p>service@gtt.com.ar</p>
                          <p>www.globaltectrade.com.ar</p>

                      </td>
                    
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <table border="1" width="100%">
                  <thead>

                      
                      <tr>
                          <th>Numero de Ticket</th>
                          <td>{{$ticket->id}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Estado de Ticket</th>
                          <td>{{$ticket->estadoTicket->status}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Tipo de Ticket</th>
                          <td>{{$ticket->tipoTicket->type}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Fecha de Ingreso a Laboratorio</th>
                          <td>{{$ticket->created_at}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Cliente</th>
                          <td>{{$ticket->contact->name . " " . $ticket->contact->lastname}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Producto</th>
                          <td>{{$ticket->products->ptype->productType . ", " . $ticket->products->marca->brandName . " " . $ticket->products->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Numero de Serie</th>
                          <td>{{$ticket->serial_number}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                         <th>Accesorios</th>
                         <td>{{$ticket->accesories}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Fecha de Devolución</th>
                          <td>{{$ticket->deliver}}</td>
                      </tr>


                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    
                      <tr>
                        
                      </tr>
                    
                    
                  </tbody>
              </table>

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>

 </html>
```

Por alguna razon en la primer tabla con y en la primer etiqueta tr>td hay una imagen y cuando utilizo esa imagen en la vista el pdf ya no carga. Si la saco, por otro lado, si carga el pdf pero sin la imagen.

Answer (score 1):

DomPDF no reconoce la función `url()` definida en Laravel. Debés utilizar la dirección absoluta desde el proyecto a tu recurso.

Ejemplo:

```
<img src="storage/backend/dist/img/axis.jpg">
```

Comment: Sigue sin reconocer la imagen. <img src="public/backend/dist/img/axis.jpg">

Comment: Revisaste que exista alguna otra función similar? La mayoría de los problemas que tuve con esa librería fueron por esa razón o por intentar importar librería externas (como bootstrap) donde me daba el mismo error que nombraste. Revisa también los tamaños (width) de la imagen que no se excedan.

Comment: yo utilizo la funcion asset() y utilizo la public folder como path